# Use the MGF to derive all moments of $X \sim N(0, \sigma)^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

> Use the moment generating function to obtain the moments of all orders of $X$ if $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$

My attempt:

The mgf of a generic $N(\mu, \sigma)^2$ is $M_X(t) = e^{\mu t}e^{(\sigma^2t^2)/2}$. So the mgf of $X$ in this particular case is

$$ M_X(t) = exp(\frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2}), ~~ t \in \mathbb{R} \tag{1} $$

Now you taylor expand the mgf to obtain

$$M_X(t) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\Biggl( \frac{\sigma^2 t^2}{2} \Biggr)^n\frac{1}{n!} \tag{2} $$

Now the objetive is the simplify the series to the form

$$ \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}c_n \frac{t^n}{n!} \tag{3} $$

In this form, the expression of $c_n$ will be the expression for $E(X^n)$.

But when simplifying $(2)$, I get:

$$ \frac{\sigma^{2n} t^{2n}}{2^n}\frac{1}{n!} = \frac{\sigma^{2n}(2n)!}{2^n n!} \frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!} = \frac{\sigma^{n}(n)!}{2^{n/2} (n/2)!} \frac{t^{n}}{(n)!}  \tag{4} $$

So you'd conclude that

$$ E(X^n) = \frac{\sigma^{n}(n)!}{2^{n/2} (n/2)!} \tag{5} $$

However, this doesn't agree with the first moment of $X$, which is $0$ since $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: You've shown this formula, but for even numbers. For odd numbers it's $0$, also from the power series. Also, the last equality in $(4)$ is false.

Comment: @Jakobian thanks. I forgot that all odd moments of a Normal = 0. About the last equality in $(4)$, my teacher did the same thing when deriving all moments of a $N(0, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The argument you transcribed from your teacher is mostly fine, except for a miscommunication in the last equality of $(4)$. Namely, $2n$ was renamed to $n$. It is less confusing if you avoid this renaming. Then, observe that $c_n=0$ if $n$ is odd since there are only even terms in the series. All that is left is to write down a formula for $c_{2n}$, which can be done by using just the first equality in $(4)$.

Comment: Today I cleared up this confusion with him. Thanks though